# How to make scrollView to scroll ImageView until the center?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Sorry for the header, I just did not know how to call it.

[image]

I want to make my scrollView able to scroll from top or bottom until the circle in the center, like LinkedIn does it:

[image]

So there you can scroll your image until the circle in the center. How can I improve my code, to achieve this?

My code is:

```
scrollView!.delegate = self
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (scrollView?.frame.width)!, (scrollView?.frame.height)!)

    if let validImage = self.avatarImage {
        self.imageView.image = validImage
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.frame = avatarImageFrame!
    }
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    scrollView?.addSubview(imageView)

    scrollView?.contentSize = (avatarImage?.size)!
    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView?.frame
    let scaleWidth = (scrollViewFrame?.size.width)! / (scrollView?.contentSize.width)!
    let scaleHeight = (scrollViewFrame?.size.height)! / (scrollView?.contentSize.height)!

    let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

    scrollView?.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView?.maximumZoomScale = 1
    scrollView?.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()
}

func centerScrollViewContents() {
    let boundsSize = scrollView?.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = imageView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize?.width {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = ((boundsSize?.width)! - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize?.height {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = ((boundsSize?.height)! - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0
    }

    contentsFrame.size.height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    imageView.frame = contentsFrame
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
}
```

Comment: are you trying to make it so the circle is contained to within the bounds of the image **or** trying to make the center of the image snap to the center of the circle?

Comment: @originaluser2 now I cannot scroll my image down to the top corner of the circle. But in the second image, it's possible. Look, at the second image the corner of the image is on the corner of the circle

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Probably what would work best with the scroll view is to set the frame of the scroll view the same as is the frame of the circle. The content size should still be the same as the background (or rather the image in your case) and when you first enter the screen the content offset should be set so that the image is in center.

So till now you can imagine a small scroll view just behind the circle but the rest of the background is missing. To fix this all you need to do is disable bound clipping on the scroll view which is set to true by default. So set "clip subviews" to false.

Now you can already see the whole image and bouncing is correct to always keep the image inside the circle but one more thing is missing. Since the scroll view is actually quite small you can see you may not interact with it outside its frame. This is a natural behavior which can be changed by overriding a method called `hitTest`. This method will return a view which should collect the interaction. So we need to subclass the superview of the scroll view:

Regardless of where you do this in the interface builder or in the code I expect you have some view (will call it background) which contains a scroll view (the small one) and an overlay (the one with the circle). The background must be subclassed and have a reference to the scroll view. Then simply override the hit test method like so:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var myFrame = frame
    myFrame.origin = CGPointZero // maybe this should be commented out

    if CGRectContainsPoint(myFrame, point) {
        return scrollView
    } else {
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

By doing this the scroll view is interactable from anywhere within the background, whole image is visible on the background, the image will always be within the circle.

Good luck.